# dynamically making onClick event?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I realise a similar issue has been asked here [Javascript - Dynamically assign onclick event in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040069/javascript-dynamically-assign-onclick-event-in-the-loop) but I think I was a bit confused and couldn't add a comment.

I'm making a series of divs dynamically, in an array "newdiv".
I want to create an onClick function which will expand the offsetHeight to the scrollHeight.

I'm trying to do this in my for loop as such:

```
newdiv[i].onclick = function() {expandThis(message_id) };
```

Where

```
message_id = message_array[i][0];
```

(the id column in the array, at message 'i')

The problem is familiar - all the made onClicks refer to the last message_id.
Is there an easy way to make the onClick for newdiv[i] refer to message_array[i][0]?

Comment: Seems like each div needs to know its own identity. Can you attach an arbitrary property to divs after you have added them to the DOM, such as newdiv[i].myid = i; then refer back to this property in your function: expandThis(this.myid);?

Comment: @Matt M: The closure approach is much better; you just need to carefully close it over the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break the closure with message_id:

```
newdiv[i].onclick = (function(id) {
                       return function() {expandThis(id) };
                    }(message_id));
```

There are a million questions like this one, e.g. [Do while javascript Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951191/do-while-javascript-problem/6951233#comment-8286824).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous function to create a closure to contain the value to be referred to.

```
function(message_id) {
  newdiv[i].onclick = function() {expandThis(message_id) };
}(message_array[i][0]);
```

JavaScript is a functional programming language without a *let* statement.  So you have to write the equivalent closure, as ugly as it looks.

Comment: Isn't the `var` statement a *let*?

Comment: In a typical functional language such as Lisp, Ocaml, or Haskell, a let statement not only assigns a value to a name but also creates a closure.  In JS, var will assign a name but does not create a closure.

Answer (score 0):

you could create the javascript code dynamically and store in in a var and then use the evalute() function and assign the result to your onclick callback.

Comment: **YUCK**. It's a lot of ugly quoting and it's going to be slower too.